# Great realtime shader tool?

Tags: tools

I often develop 2D games. I would like to know if there's a program like EvalDraw out there, that makes it easy to quickly make (for example) a square, out of a black quad, and then write some shader code, and see how that shader code modifies the square in realtime.

That would be really great for my future development processes.

**Edit:**
The shader tool must work with HLSL.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try these online shaders editors:
https://www.shadertoy.com/ 
https://shaderoo.org/ 
http://glslsandbox.com/ 
http://pixelshaders.com/editor/ 
http://shdr.bkcore.com/

Comment: Is there an HLSL equivalent for ShaderToy?

Comment: I think, there is no HLSL equivalent, beacouse shadertoy use WebGL, and WebGL use glsl. Mayby somewhere is equivalent in silverlight, but I don't know.

Comment: I found this http://shazzam-tool.com - there is HLSL

Comment: Yes, but specifically for WPF and Silverlight. Are there any for general XNA stuff?

Answer (score 6):

[RenderMonkey](http://developer.amd.com/archive/gpu/rendermonkey/pages/default.aspx) and [FX Composer](http://developer.nvidia.com/fx-composer) were both tools like this, although they've been relatively abandoned recently. 3D modelling tools like Max or Maya often usually have shader/effect/material pipelines built in, but they are probably prohibitively expensive.

Comment: I was looking for an editor yesterday and instinctively visited the Nvidia and ATI developer sites. I wonder why these have been left by the wayside?

Comment: I would venture to guess it's due to the fact that shader semantics tend to be coupled to their associated rendering framework or engine, and as those engines increase in complexity a general-purpose tool becomes more and more difficult to write.

Answer (score 0):

Insprired by shadertoy and glsl-sandbox, I make a hlsl version of them.
https://github.com/vinjn/HlslShaderToy

There is no live coding support for the moment, you can use your favorite editor to write the shader. If the content is changed, HlslShaderToy detects it, and reload the shader automatically. So you can pretend that it's a realtime shader tool.

There is also some fancy features:
 - loads local image as a texture
 - loads internet image as a texture